# Dúvida sobre método construtor

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos

Galera comecei a estudar java e tenho uma dúvida sobre o método principal, tenho um projeto a fazer e gostaria de fazer se no método principal posso por funções e outros métodos como por exemplo cadastrar usuários e etc.

Comment: Acabei de responder sua pergunta, mas sugiro que leia as diretrizes da comunidade de [como fazer uma boa pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: No título vc menciona construtor, mas na pergunta vc fala sobre o método principal (seria o `main`?) Se for sobre construtor, dê uma lida em https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/73530/112052 - De qualquer forma, é importante [edit] a pergunta e deixar mais claro qual é a sua dúvida

Comment: Voce pode chamar qualquer tipo de funções dentro da sua classe "main", mas o recomendado, é que tu separe as responsabilidades do seu projeto, de modo que cada classe tenha uma responsabilidade Unica. 
Ex: se voce tem um método privado em outra classe (public user cadUser), que te a função de cadastrar um usuário. Tu pode chamar ele na sua classe main sem problemas.
BOM.... não sei se é isso que tu quer, mas, foi isso que intendi com sua pergunta. Sugiro que tu de uma lida em algum livro sobre OO
https://www.caelum.com.br/apostilas

Answer (score 2):

**Construtores Java**

> Um construtor em Java é um método especial usado para inicializar objetos. O construtor é chamado quando um objeto de uma classe é criado. Pode ser usado para definir valores iniciais para atributos de objetos. Observe que o nome do construtor deve corresponder ao nome da classe e não pode ter um tipo de retorno (como void) e o mesmo é chamado quando o objeto é criado.
>
> Todas as classes possuem construtores por padrão: se você não criar um construtor de classe, o Java criará um para você. No entanto, você não poderá definir valores iniciais para atributos de objeto.

**Parâmetros do construtor**

> Os construtores também podem usar os parâmetros, que são usados ​​para inicializar os atributos.
>
> **NOTA:** Você pode ter quantos parâmetros quiser.

**Segue um exemplo básico:**

```
// Criando a Classe denominada MyClass
//CLASSE
public class MyClass {
    int x;  // Criando o atributo da classe
    
    // Criando o construtor da classe MyClass
    public MyClass() {
        x = 5;  // Definindo o valor inicial do Atributo X da Classe
    }
}


// MAIN
public static void main(String[] args) {
    MyClass myObj = new MyClass(); // Criando o objeto da classe MyClass (Isso vai chamar o construtor)
    System.out.println(myObj.x); // Exibindo no Console o valor do atributo X da classe MyClass
    // Outputs 5
}
```

Podemos também iniciarmos a classe outros tipos de atributos e ainda mais, outras instancias de classe:

```
//CLASSE
public class MyClass {
    String nome = nome;
    private int x;  // Criando o atributo da classe
    public double y;
    protected long z;
    private final MyClassTwo myClassTwo;
    
    // Criando o construtor da classe MyClass
    public MyClass(int x, int y, int z) {
        this.x = x; // Atribuindo o valor a variável, quando instancia o objeto da classe "new"
        this.y = y; // Atribuindo o valor a variável, quando instancia o objeto da classe "new"
        this.z = z; // Atribuindo o valor a variável, quando instancia o objeto da classe "new"
        this.myClassTwo = new MyClassTwo(); // Instanciando uma outra classe dentro da classe MyClass

        this.nome = "MINHA CLASSE!" // Definindo o valor inicial do Atributo X da Classe
    }
}


// MAIN
public static void main(String[] args) {
    MyClass myObj = new MyClass(1, 2, 3); // Criando o objeto da classe MyClass (Isso vai chamar o construtor)
    System.out.println(myObj.nome);
    System.out.println(myObj.x);
    System.out.println(myObj.y);
    System.out.println(myObj.z);
    System.out.println(myObj.myClassTwo);
}
```

[FONTE DE PESQUISA: W3-SCHOOLS](https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_constructors.asp)

**NOTA:**

> Leia também sobre
>
> - [Classes / Objetos Java](https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_classes.asp)
> - [Atributos de Classe Java](https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_class_attributes.asp)
> - [Modificadores](https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_modifiers.asp)
> - [Encapsulamento](https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_encapsulation.asp)